# Embedded video in pdf file doesn't work in Preview

Tags: video, pdf, preview

I worked with LaTeX and I created a pdf document that contains some embedded videos. The videos pop up when I click on them and this functionality works just find in Adobe Reader. But when I try to do the same on Preview it doesn't work, and it gives me this sound as if there's an error or something, just that no error is shown on the screen. Can someone know how to make Preview work with embedded videos on pdf files?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, either Acrobat or Adobe Reader would be considered standards for viewing a given PDF. Since your PDF does not display the embedded video in Preview, this would indicate a bug within Preview that [needs to be reported to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/).

In addition to decribing how you created the PDF, they'd need a copy of that PDF for testing.

Comment: The pdf file looks fine on preview. Just the videos don't play

Comment: I would consider that to be the bug (i.e., embedded video does not display).